# Использование строк при преобразовании в десятичную систему счисления

Tags: c

**Задача**

Дано число в двоичном, восьмеричном, шестнадцатеричном счислении. Преобразовать в десятеричное число. Написать программу, которая считывает базис счисления и последовательность цифр исходного числа. Последовательность цифр считывается в массив типа char. После преобразования в десятеричном счислении, выводить последовательность десятеричных цифр. Каждое преобразование реализовать в виде отдельной функции.

**Входные данные**
"Базис счисления" "последовательность цифр согласно базису" Последовательность цифр не более 6, без знака, если введено более 6 цифр, обработать первые 6. Максимальное кол-во цифр 10.

**Выходные данные**

В первой строке дублируется ввод.
Во второй строке десятеричное представление результата. 
Если номер базиса введен не верно, то во второй строке вывести: ***Base is wrong***

Если исходное число задано некорректно, во второй строке вывести: *Number is wrong*

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int enter(int bazis, char str[10], int error, int result) {
    int error = 0;
    char str[10] = {0};
    char error_message_1[14] = "Base is wrong"; 
    char error_message_2[16] = "Number is wrong";
    printf("Введите базис и последовательность: ");
    scanf("%d %6s", &bazis, str);
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0' && i < 6; i++) {
    }
if(bazis != 2 && bazis != 8 && bazis != 16) {
        error++;

    }
else {

    if(bazis == 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
                error = error + 2;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(bazis == 8) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '7') {
                error = error + 2;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(bazis == 16) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] < '0' || str[i] > 'F') {
                error = error + 2;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    if(result = 1) {
        result = error_message_1;
    }
    else {
        result = error_message_2;
    }
    system("pause");
    return(result);

}

int main(void) {
    int enter();
    return(0);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я не совсем хорошо понимаю принцип работ со строками, моя программа для определения корректности ввода работает лишь на половину правильно. Если я введу последовательность из 6 и более цифр, то всё работает, а если меньше 6, то программа уже выводит number is wrong. В первую очередь хотелось бы понять почему так? Код вроде бы правильный. Второй мой вопрос заключается в том, что так же не очень хорошо понимаю принцип работы пользовательских функций в Си,  в какой последовательности они выполняются? Как передавать значения из одной функции в другую? И как можно было бы короче записать эту программу, потому что мне кажется, что у меня слишком много условного оператора и это всё можно было бы реализовать как то иначе. И правильный ли у меня код с точки зрения процедурного программирования?

Comment: Есть хитрый трюк чтобы избежать таких проблем - писать константу слева: `1 = result`, тогда компилятор вам сразу укажет на ошибку. Ваша программа не работает совсем так как точка входа задана неверно, а `int enter();` является объявлением функции, а не вызовом.

Comment: А как правильно сделать? И как правильно вызвать функцию?

Comment: Вызвать функцию: `int result = enter();`. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Да, чувствую, спасибо большое